# Asp.Net Core Url.Action use WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two types of controller in my application. One WebApi controller and one MVC controller. With the following structure of my project:

```
Project
|-- Controllers
|   |-- Api
|   |   |-- AccountController
|   |   |-- ...
|   |-- AccountController
|   |-- ...
```

As you can see, I have AccountController twice in two different namespaces though. The one in the folder Api is the WebApi controller and the one under Controllers is a MVC controller.

I would like to use `@Url.Action("GetAll", "Account")` inside my view to generate a link to my WebApi controller. How do I differentiate between the Api controller and the MVC controller. How can I tell it whether to use the Api or MVC controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: you can't. `Url.Action` has no capability to distinguish by namespace; you'll need unique controller names. This is part of the reason why it's typical to add `Api` in the an API controller's name, i.e. `AccountController` and `AccountApiController`.

If you really want to use `AccountController` for both, your only real option is to use areas. You can create an `Api` area, rather than just a subfolder under `Controllers`, and then you can do:

```
@Url.Action("GetAll", "Account", new { area = "Api" })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Chris! I saw that it was able to distinguish only if the Action that I call is unique in both controllers. However, when the same Action is specified in both Controllers, the selection of the appropriate Controller is kind of random. 
I guess that I will have to add the Api keyword in my Controller names then.